# Setting an element of an array to a value

Tags: syntax

This may be a simple syntax question, but for some reason I've been having trouble with it. Suppose we have an array `arr`, and we want to set one of the elements to a particular value (say, 7). It's easy to do this manually:

```
arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
arr[[1, 2]] = 7;
arr

Out: {{1, 7}, {3, 4}}
```

How do we do this when the index we want to modify is stored as a list? It's easy to use `Extract` to return the current element at that location:

```
indices = {2, 2};
Extract[arr, indices]

Out: 4
```

But attempting to set it equal to a value (say, 13) gives errors:

```
Extract[arr, indices] = 13

Out: Set::write: Tag Extract in Extract[{{1,7},{3,4}},{2,2}] is Protected. >>
```

Similarly, using `Part` gives errors when done the naive way:

```
arr[[##]] & @@ indices = 13

Out: Set::write: Tag Apply in (arr[[##1]]&)@@{2,2} is Protected. >>
```

Of course, I can sort of do it manually in the following way:

```
arr[[indices[[1]], indices[[2]]]] = 13
arr

Out: {{1, 7}, {3, 13}}
```

But this becomes cumbersome when dealing with arrays which are very deep. So the question is, is there a way to set an element in an array to a value without having to enter the expression manually?

Comment: Try `(arr[[#1, #2]] = 13;) & @@ indices`?

Comment: @LeoFang `##` will do too.

Comment: Yup, seems right- using `arr[[##]] = 13; & @@ indices` seems to be easies.

Comment: @Kuba, cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single level `indices` (your example):

```
arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; indices = {2, 2};
(arr[[#1, #2]] = 13;) & @@ indices
arr
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 13}}

Double level `indices` (in case you need to replace more than one element)

```
arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; indices = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}; newValues = {56, 78};
(arr[[#1, #2]] = newValues[[Position[indices, {#1, #2}][[1, 1]]]];) & @@@ indices
arr
```

> {{1, 56}, {3, 78}}

Answer (score 2):

another approach:

```
arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
indices = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}};
newValues = {56, 78};

arr = ReplacePart[arr, Thread[indices -> newValues]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 56}, {3, 78}}
> ```

or

```
(arr[[##2]] = #) & @@@ Join[List /@ newValues, indices, 2];
arr
```

> ```
> {{1, 56}, {3, 78}}
> ```